# Adding rows dynamically in a table with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table

I have to develop a table in D3.js. The problem is that the data to put in the table isn't static, but I have to add a new row and update some value in a row dynamically.
Usually every tutorial that I have read on the web, the code is like that:

```
var table = d3.select("body").append("table");

    thead = table.append("thead");
    tbody = table.append("tbody")


    thead.append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(rowLabel)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d;
    });
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(dataTable)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");

    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function (d, i) {
            console.log(d);
            return d;
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d;
        });
```

where dataTable is an array of array.
But I take the data to put in the table by a socket like this:

```
socket.on('trendList', function (data) {
      if (data is new) {
          add a new row in the table;
      } else update data in the table;
});
```

The columns of the table have a string value and a counter, so for every new data in the socket method I receive, I have to check if the data is present and increment the counter.
How I can do it? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by *joining* data with DOM elements. I highly recommend Mike Bostock's [Thinking with Joins](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) for getting a handle on this feature. You don't need to do any of the diffing and checking for new data, that is all handled by D3. One thing you will need to do though, is to [give each cell/row a unique key](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) so that new vs. existing rows can be appropriately determined by D3.